# How to improve Postgres query for long strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with 500,000 rows. It has two columns, "id" and "description". I am indexing properly on id.

I find that when the text in the descriptions fields are small (like 2 characters), I can run my queries very quickly, but when the descriptions are 1000 characters, it takes much longer to get the data back.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? I am already compressing the text and using partitions.

Comment: Are you querying/filtering on description, or just returning description?

Comment: Start here and see what it's doing https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: @JNevill I am querying on id and just returning description

Comment: Also, if you are compressing, there is some overhead to decompress. It's hard to say for sure what could be causing the slowness. Longer descriptions mean more data through the pipe so perhaps it's network related too?

Comment: @JNevill Compression/decompression is occurring outside of the database. As for network issues, I'm running on localhost at the moment.

Comment: @msanford I ran an explain analyze and confirmed that the idex scan is happening. The issue is related to the description length in some way.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)